# Why do I get null when I getElementById?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS, and reading Javascript Dom, I'm trying to figure out one of the example in my book!

here is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Image Gallery</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type = "text/javascript"  src="showPic.js"></script>
<h1>Snapshots</h1>
        <ul id = "image">
        <li>
            <a href="images/fall.JPG"   title = "water display"> Fall</a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="images/sun.JPG"  title = "sunshine"> Sunshine</a>
        </li> 

        <li>
            <a href="images/tree.jpg"  title = "tree"> Green</a>
        </li> 

        <li>
            <a href="images/yellow.JPG"  title = "yellow sun">Filter</a>
        </li>  

      </ul>  
       <img id = "placeholeder" src="images/rise.jpg" alt = "my image gallery"/>  
        <p id="description"> Choose an image</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

here is my javaScript code

```
function showPic(whichPic) {
    var source = whichPic.getAttribute("href");
    var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholeder");
    placeholder.setAttribute("src", source);
    description.firstChild.nodeValue = text;
   }

    var text = whichPic.getAttribute("title");
    var description = document.getElementById("description");
    function perpareGallery() {
        var gallery = document.getElementById("image");
        var links = gallery.getElementsByTagName("a");

        for(var i = 0 ; i<links.length; i++) {
            links[i].onclick = function() {
                showPic(this);
                return false;
            }
        }   
    }
```

my code didnt getting anything from id = image. and I checked many times dont know what is wrong....

Comment: probably need document.ready

Comment: Where is the closing `}` for the `showPic` function? Right now `perpareGallery` looks like it's inside the `showPic` function.

Comment: exactly the whole code?

Comment: Now it's whole code, I miss paste two lines.....

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be no code that actually runs the `perpareGallery()` function.

After you fix that, it might still not work if you run `perpareGallery()` before the elements in HTML (like your `a` elements) are parsed and rendered. So, you might want to do something like:

```
window.onload = prepareGalery;
```

Although there are way better ways to set-up events, this will run your function after all HTML is parsed.

Comment: I just found out I miss paste two lines which include } of  showPic()

Answer (score 0):

Two advices on how to track down your issue:

1) All browsers have a so called **javascript console**. It shows you all syntax error with your code. For firefox and chromium the keyboard shortcut **F12** turns it on/off

If you run your code and open the javascript console you'll see this error:

```
ReferenceError: whichPic is not defined
```

In your example it looks as if the line `var text = whichPic.getAttribute("title");` belongs to the function `showPic(whichPic)`, but it doesn't.

2) You should format your code to not get lost. Your current code formatted:

```
function showPic(whichPic) {
  var source = whichPic.getAttribute("href");
  var placeholder = document.getElementById("placeholeder");
  placeholder.setAttribute("src", source);
  description.firstChild.nodeValue = text;
}

var text = whichPic.getAttribute("title");
var description = document.getElementById("description");

function perpareGallery() {
  var gallery = document.getElementById("image");
  var links = gallery.getElementsByTagName("a");

  for(var i = 0 ; i<links.length; i++) {
    links[i].onclick = function() {
      showPic(this);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

If you now take a look to the formatted code, it no longer looks as if `whichPic` is used inside of `showPic(whichPic)` but outside of the scope. The error makes perfectly sense.

You might want to move it inside of the function, **before** you use it.